# Angular hybrid(Ng1/Ng13): No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver$1! while using downgradeComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, migrate, angular-hybrid

After I updated the angularJS controller in the angular13 component and tried to call it via angularJS + downgradeComponent, the markup on the page ceased to be displayed and an error of this kind appears in the console. Has anyone come across a similar one? Can I connect and use the new component incorrectly?

**error log**

```
angular.js:15635 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ComponentFactoryResolver$1 -> ComponentFactoryResolver$1 -> ComponentFactoryResolver$1]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver$1!
    at NullInjector.get (vendor.js:101314)
    at R3Injector.get (vendor.js:101509)
    at R3Injector.get (vendor.js:101509)
    at R3Injector.get (vendor.js:101509)
    at NgAdapterInjector.get (vendor.js:133218)
    at doDowngrade (static.mjs:771)
    at eval (static.mjs:801)
    at SyncPromise.then (static.mjs:631)
    at Object.link (static.mjs:801)
    at angular.js:1391 '<text class="ng-scope">'
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    textComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...upgradedServices,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }

  public ngDoBootstrap(ref: ApplicationRef) {
    ref.bootstrap(AppComponent);

    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [bootstrapModule.name], { strictDi: true });
    setUpLocationSync(this.upgrade);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ){
  }
}
```

**ajs-upgraded-providers.ts**

```
export const upgradedServices = [

    {
        provide: 'routeProvider',
        deps: ['$injector'],
        useFactory(i){return i.get('routeProvider')},
    }
    {
        provide: '$rootscope',
        deps: ['$injector'],
        useFactory(i){return i.get('$rootscope')},
    },

    {
        provide: 'CurrentUser',
        deps: ['$injector'],
        useFactory(i){return i.get('CurrentUser')},
    },

    {
        provide: '$routeProvider',
        deps: ['$injector'],
        useFactory(i){return i.get('$routeProvider')}
    },

]
```

**text.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'text',
  templateUrl: './text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text.component.sass']
})
export class textComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  termsOfUseUrl: any;
  termsOfUseText: any;

  constructor(
    //AJS upgraded services
    @Inject('routeProvider') public routeProvider: any,
    @Inject('$rootscope') public $rootscope: any,
    @Inject('CurrentUser') public CurrentUser: any,
    @Inject('$routeProvider') public $routeProvider: any,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.CurrentUser.isAuthenticated()
    this.$rootscope.view.footer = !this.isLoggedIn
    this.$rootscope.view.isPublic = !this.isLoggedIn
  }

}
```

**ajsModule.ts**

```
angular.module('angularjsmodule', [
  'common.Route',
  'config',
  'ngRoute',
  'user.services.currentUser',
])
.directive('text', downgradeComponent({component: textComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory)
.config(AngularJsModuleConfig);

AngularJsModuleConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider', 'routeProvider'];
function AngularJsModuleConfig($routeProvider, routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when(routeProvider.bootstrapModule.text, {
    title: 'Text',
    template: '<text></text>',
    reloadOnSearch: false,
    controllerAs: 'view',
    options: {
      bypassAuth: true,
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: I would add a final question, like: "How can I solve this? What causes this problem?"

Comment: @EuberDeveloper Thank you for your advice! Already changed it